# Save image/table from a webpage while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I would need to scrape a image from this website: https://web.archive.org/web/
for example for `stackoverflow, towardsdatascience`.

```
URL

stackoverflow.com
towardsdatascience.com
```

I do not know how to include information on the table/image within

```
<div class="sparkline" style="width: 1225px;"><div id="wm-graph-anchor"><div id="wm-ipp-sparkline" title="Explore captures for this URL" style="height: 77px;"><canvas class="sparkline-canvas" width="1225" height="75" alt="sparklines"></canvas></div></div><div id="year-labels"><span class="sparkline-year-label">1996</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">1997</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">1998</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">1999</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2000</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2001</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2002</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2003</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2004</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2005</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2006</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2007</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2008</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2009</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2010</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2011</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2012</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2013</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2014</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2015</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2016</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2017</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2018</span><span class="sparkline-year-label">2019</span><span class="sparkline-year-label selected-year">2020</span></div></div>
```

i.e. the image where the timeline is shown through years.
I would like to save per each website this image/table, if possible.
I tried to write some code, but it misses this part:

```
import json
import requests


def my_function(file):
    urls = list(set(file.URL.tolist()))

   df_url= pd.DataFrame(columns=['URL'])
   df_url['URL']=urls

   api_url = 'https://web.archive.org/__wb/search/metadata'

   for url in df_url['URL']:
      res = requests.get(api_url, params={'q': url})   
      # part to scrape the image
   return

my_function(df)
```

Can you give me some input on how to get those images?

Answer (score 0):

If you have each image URL in the for loop, you can download the images using python library `urllib.request` function `urlretrive`:

First import it at the beginning of the script using

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import urllib.request
```

And then download them using

```
for url in df_url['URL']:
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path))
```

If you don't to save using URL basename, then don't make first 2 imports.

Comment: thanks Wasif. Do you know if it looks right the tag to import iv class="sparkline" ? I do not know which one corresponds to that image. Update: it does not work as I am getting a ValueError: `ValueError: unknown url type:`  . The url type is correct, but if I use url lib.request I get this error